# Is the magnetic field strength of a star predictable from mass, composition, age and angular momentum alone?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, star-formation, magnetic-field, stellar-astrophysics

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/37082/7982) to *Which stellar properties can we describe as “first principles” in which we can derive the rest?* contains an intriguing bit:

> That states that composition and mass are the two key properties, assuming that the star is in hydrostatic equilibrium and derives its energy from nuclear reactions.
>
> I agree with Rob that rotation (angular momentum) is a key second-order effect, **and I'd add magnetic field strength as well.**

which triggered an intriguing [comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/37077/which-stellar-properties-can-we-describe-as-first-principles-in-which-we-can-d/37082#comment73971_37082):

> Is the magnetic field strength generally independent of the other three properties?

**Question:** Is the magnetic field strength of a star predictable from mass, composition, age and angular momentum? Or is it somewhat random or at least unpredictable from those alone for some reason?

I suppose it could be somehow inherited, influenced or acquired from its surroundings during formation, or arise from some random or chaotic process, but I have no idea.